# Angular Router Route priority

Tags: angular

I am having a modular application and I faced a problem. Routes initialized in the application by its order. For ex core-routes.module routes initialized as foollows:

```
const coreRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "maintenance",
    component: MaintenanceComponent,
    data: { title: "Under maintenance" }
  },
  { path: "**", component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

Public routes are as follows:

```
const publicRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent, data: { title: "FoodApp" } },
  {
    path: "signup",
    component: UserSignupComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthService],
    data: {
      title: "Signup",
      roles: ["guest"]
    }
  },
  {
    path: "login",
    component: UserLoginComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthService],
    data: {
      title: "Login",
      roles: ["guest"]
    }
  }
];
```

In submodules public routes must be indentifed before the core routes. because otherwise NotFoundComponent path wildcard will be used for all routes... I thought there is a way to setup the priority for the route. but there is none. Does anybody have ideas? Coz currently the only was - is to place core.module bellow others modules.

So the main question is - how to setup routes so NotFoundComponent route is bellow others???

Comment: Route priority cascades because the order of the array never changes, so first index of route will be used before. All wildcards should be placed at the end of the array. Why can't you have the submodule paths > core paths > wildcard paths ?

Comment: @Baruch I can. But when routes are spread across different modules . Its hard to keep track of that.... I

Comment: a `'**'` should be present only once, at the highest level of routing you have. Besides, isn't what `forRoot` and `forChild` are supposed to handle ? (guenine question)

Comment: not only once - but bellow other routes as well... Or you'll see only NotFound component :)

Comment: Why not unshift the routes of those modules to the highest level module route config? That way you only have one routing config to worry about.

Comment: You can achieve it by first unshifting the new routes to `this.router.config`, and then resetting the router using `this.router.resetConfig(this.router.config)`